# Can't find/enable virtualization

Tags: bios, virtualization

I have a AMD Athlon 7850 Black Edition and I can't seem to find VT-x or AMD-V. I've looked literally every where in my BIOS. My BIOS is a ASUSTeK M2N68-AM Plus (AM2). I looked it up and yes, my CPU does AMD-V (virtualization) technology. I just cannot find it anywhere in my BIOS options. Oh and if it helps any, I have to use my DEL key to get to my BIOS options.

Comment: Perhaps your bios does not support enabling or disableing vt-x.  How about booting linux and doing `grep svm /proc/cpuinfo`.  If it is there, then it is on.

Comment: Regarding the user manual for your Asus motherboard, you should have a parameter called `Secure Virtual Machine Mode`. You have to set it to `Enabled` http://www.manualowl.com/m/Asus/M2N68-AM-PLUS/Manual/264088?page=32